# Circuit to measure RF signal bandwidth?

Tags: rf

I'm designing an RF circuit which needs to classify signals into two categories according to their bandwidth. The signal of interest will be either

a) A series of frequency hopping packets with narrow bandwidth (~2MHz)

b) A series of fixed frequency packets with wide bandwidth (~8MHz)

Due to cost constraints, I'd like to keep the digital side to a microcontroller instead of a high end DSP/FPGA, so I'm trying to do as much as possible in the analog domain, prior to injecting signals into the MCU's ADC.

My approach is to build this like an analog spectrum analyzer with two RBW filters. After two stages of down conversion, I will be working with an IF of 10MHz. So I'm thinking of splitting the IF signal into two paths and constructing two opamp based active bandpass filters (with different bandwidths), followed by peak detectors. My hope is that after some characterization of the noise floor and some calibration, I should be able to see very different voltage levels/patterns in the narrow vs wide path for the two different signals. This isn't a metrology problem, as I'm not interested in the absolute power of the signal. It's only a classification problem ("which type of packet did I just detect?").

I am wondering if this is a good approach or whether there's a simpler method I'm not familiar with. Happy to discuss more technical details, but due to the sensitive nature of the project I cannot reveal the exact application and use case. That said, it's kind of urgent.

EDIT: Some clarifications (from questions below).

The signals are in well defined channels of several bands and the LO will be sweeping with as much as 1ms of dwell time on each channel for examination. Both signals are expected to be at least 6dB above the noise floor.

There is hardly any interference expected. The purpose of the classification is to identify the wideband signal, lock onto it (stop sweeping) and then perform a set of other actions.

EDIT 2: It is possible for the hopping narrowband signal to appear at any channel in the band, without the wideband signal present. Once the wideband signal appears though, that channel will not be used for frequency hopping again and the wideband signal will persist for a while. That's why it's important to differentiate them by bandwidth. The actions will be different depending on which signal is detected.

Comment: What is the center frequency? Fixed? Variable? Are there any other sources to beware of (e.g. an antenna in space)?  Or can we assume the signal of interest is all there is?  What amplitude? And how fast and accurate does the decision need to be?

Comment: Also, when you say "frequency hopping", does that mean the hopping itself is within such a bandwidth? Or is that the transmission bandwidth per channel, and thus the hopping covers a wider spectrum?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I'm responding here:

Center frequency is swept at the LO so the target channel will be at the center of the IF signal. That said, I'm very flexible as to what IF frequency I use, so 10MHz isn't set in stone. In terms of speed, I can afford about 1ms per channel.
As to why I need to do this? I need to positively identify the wideband signal and lock onto it. That's all I can say.